# CKContainer requestApplicationPermission Network Error 1202

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to fetch `iCloud` account details from my app on my `iPhone`.But the `requestApplicationPermission` gives me following error.

```
  let container = CKContainer.default()

  container.requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } }
```

Error:

> "Network Failure" (4/NSURLErrorDomain:-1202); "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “gateway.icloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."

The same code runs fine on simulator.
I have tried installing geotrust global ca certificate on the iPhone and enabling trust in certificate trust settings but it did not work.
Please suggest a solution for the same.

Comment: Is the date and time correct on your phone? Are you connect via the same wifi as your computer that was running the simulator?  Do you have a VPN active on your phone?

Comment: Hey @Paulw11 , thanks a lot..setting date and time to automatic resolved the issue! But could you please explain how that worked?

Comment: If the time skew between the server and the client is too great then the TLS handshake will fail. Your problem may also be as simple as the device time being earlier than the certificates validity start date or later than the end date